# Using swichMap on merge observables of debounce and non-debounce

Tags: angular, typescript, merge, rxjs, observable

Basically, I have 2 observables.

1. `obseravableClickBtn` will send request at once
2. `observableInputText` will send request debounce by 3 seconds.

Code:

```
obseravableClickBtn = Observable.fromEvent(Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementsById('btnSearch'), 'click')

observableInputText = Observable.fromEvent(this.textBoxInput1.nativeElement, 'keyup')
.merge(Observable.fromEvent(this.textBoxInput2.nativeElement, 'keyup')).debounceTime(3000)
```

During the 3 seconds debounce from `observableInputText`, if `btnSearch` is clicks, I want to cancel `observableInputText` observable and immediately send request

I try to use:

```
const mergeObservable=obseravableClickBtn.merge(observableInputText).switchMap(
()=>sendRequest());
```

But still, 2 request will be made if I clicks `btnSearch` during the 3 debounce seconds after I input. I only want one observable run at a time. Is there any other operator function like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try takeUntil operator.

```
searchClick$: Subject = new Subject();
obseravableClickBtn.subscribe(() => {
   // button clicked
   searchClick$.next(true);
});



 observableInputText = Observable.fromEvent(this.textBoxInput1.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .merge(Observable.fromEvent(this.textBoxInput2.nativeElement, 'keyup')).pipe(debounceTime(3000), takeUntil(searchClick$));
```